# Remove duplicated HTML elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this python code snippet :

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open("source.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')


z = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'contributor'})
print(z)
print("---")
print(type(z))
```

that returns me this

```
[<span class="contributor">Andrew</span>, 
<span class="contributor">John</span>,
<span class="contributor">Andrew</span>,
<span class="contributor">Maria</span>]
---
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

Be careful z type returns `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` .
Also the elements of z are not strings .
`print(type(z[0]))` returns `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Do you have any idea how can I remove the whole duplicated span element ? ( e.g `Andrew` is duplicated 2 times )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each element of `z`, then keep track of which elements have already seen by using a `set`. Then, if an element has already been seen, just remove it from `z`:

```
import bs4


with open("source.html") as fp:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')


z = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'contributor'})

used = set()
for el in z:
    if el.text not in used:
        used.add(el.text)
    else:
        z.remove(el)

print(z)
print(type(z))
```

Alternatively, you can use `el.decompose()` instead of `z.remove(el)` and this will destroy the element, but leave an empty node:

```
import bs4


with open("source.html") as fp:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')


z = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'contributor'})

used = set()
for el in z:
    if el.text not in used:
        used.add(el.text)
    else:
        el.decompose()

print(z)
print(type(z))
```

Comment: Does not work. Be careful z returns `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`. Also the elements of z are not strings . `print(type(z[0]))` returns `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`

Comment: @AndrewP. Do you want the output to also be a `ResultSet`?

Comment: Not really. It can be any type as output. Basically after duplication removal I want to inject the cleaned one back into my source html

Comment: @AndrewP. I've updated my answer. Does it work for you now?

Comment: Sadly no. I get same output as before I did

Comment: @AndrewP. What is that output? It's working fine for me.

Comment: @AndrewP. Are the duplicate elements not being removed, or are the types wrong?

Comment: My output is `z` is `[<span class="contributor">John</span>, <span class="contributor">Andrew</span>, <span class="contributor">Maria</span>]`, `type(z)` is `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`, and `type(z[0])` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`. Nothing is a string or a list and no elements are duplicated.

Comment: I still get duplicates when changing the source : """<html> <div class="contributors"> <span class="contributor" title="email: andrei01@yahoo.com">andreidev</span> <span class="contributor" title="email: cast@gmail.com">Frank</span> <span class="contributor" title="email: andrei1@github.com">andreidev</span> <span class="contributor" title="email: maryoer@users.inoreply.gthub.com">mary1</span> </div> </html>"""

Comment: @AndrewP. What code are you using to change the source? Your question doesn't say anything about changing the source.

Comment: If your question is primarily about changing the source **after** you get a list without duplicates, then consider asking a new question, as these aren't really the same question.

Comment: I do not use any code for changing the source. Seems that adding titles in the span element would occur duplicates with your code.

Comment: @AndrewP. Oh, I see. You want to remove duplicates with the same text, not the same exact code.

Comment: @AndrewP. I've updated my answer to work with the text, not the code. Can you try again?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed a quite dumb html content but it worked, you can simply do `a = list(set(z))` and it will remove the duplicates, I tested it :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#assuming a dumb HTML
assume_html = """
<html>
    <span class="contributor">Andrew</span>
    <span class="contributor">John</span>
    <span class="contributor">Andrew</span>
    <span class="contributor">Maria</span>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(assume_html, 'html.parser')

z = soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'contributor'})
for element in z :
    print("element ", element, type(element))
print("---")
print(type(z))
print("------")

a = list(set(z))
for new_element in a :
    print("new_element ", new_element, type(new_element))
print("---")
print(type(a))
```

Here is the output :

```
element  <span class="contributor">Andrew</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
element  <span class="contributor">John</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>      
element  <span class="contributor">Andrew</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>    
element  <span class="contributor">Maria</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>     
---
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
------
new_element  <span class="contributor">Andrew</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
new_element  <span class="contributor">John</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>  
new_element  <span class="contributor">Maria</span> <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> 
---
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: My answer is kind of the same as Michael, I was typing it he replied faster :P

Comment: If I would replace your assume_html with this one : """<html>
    <div class="contributors">
<span class="contributor" title="email: andrei01@yahoo.com">andreidev</span>
<span class="contributor" title="email: cast@gmail.com">Frank</span>
<span class="contributor" title="email: andrei1@github.com">andreidev</span>
<span class="contributor" title="email: maryoer@users.inoreply.gthub.com">mary1</span>
    </div>
</html>""" I would still get duplicates

Comment: Oh it is because they do not have the same email address, you have 2 users called andreidev with 2 different mail address, do you still need help ? I just read that Michael solution works.